# Comparing to undefined not working every time

Tags: javascript

When I try to check for a function parameter if it is defined, and use

```
 if (variablename === undefined) { do something };
```

sometimes it works as intendend, but sometimes(mainly very early on, when some scripts are possibly still loading) I get a javascript error, that states that

> variablename is undefined

If I use

```
if (typeof variablename == 'undefined')
```

it works everytime.

**Is the === undefined has some prerequisites, or what could be the problem?**

Comment: `console.log(variablename)` will result in *variablename is undefined*. However, `var variablename = undefined; console.log(variablename);` will just print undefined

Comment: if a name is not defined it will throw an error, if the value is undefined it works.

Comment: You are doing something wrong if you don't know whether your variables are declared or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that `variablename === undefined` does is to read the value of `variablename`.

It could be a variable which has the *value* `undefined` (which will work fine) or it could be a variable that isn't defined at all … which will throw a reference error.

Using `typeof` won't throw a reference error.